# Understanding the expression "cœur d'artichaut"

Tags: argot

I don't quite understand the expression

> avoir un cœur d'artichaut

Lots of sites say it means to easily fall in love, and to do it often ("Tomber facilement et souvent amoureux"), and each time the person falls in love, is associated with one of the "feuilles". I don't understand the analogy and I suspect the origin of that relies on French itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'artichaut se fait *croquer* feuille par feuille, avant d'arriver au 'foin' qui recouvre le cœur.

Or dans les chansons populaires, souvent l'amour se croque.

Avoir un cœur d'artichaut, c'est se le faire croquer feuille par feuille, se disperser dans des aventures avec des amours différentes.

> Cœur d'artichaut tu donnes une feuille à tout le monde ("Embrasse les
>   tous" de Georges Brassens).

N.B. C’est un vrai plat de pauvre. C’est le seul plat que quand t’as fini de manger, t’en as plus dans ton assiette que quand t’as commencé! (Coluche).